# swagger ui not picking apimodelproperty annotations from a generic field

Tags: java, spring, swagger

why is this annotation

```
        @ApiModelProperty(allowableValues="range[-infinity, 50]")
        private MyCustomGenericProp<String> text;
```

not getting picked up by swagger ui on a field declared as a parameterized  generic?
it works for simple String fields

Answer (score 1):

adding the annotation property DataType="java.lang.String" fixed it

```
@ApiModelProperty(dataType="java.lang.String",allowableValues="range[-infinity, 50]")
private MyCustomGenericProp<String> text;
```